# jQuery UI - tooltip position is wrong

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, position, jquery-tooltip

I am using jQuery tooltip to create html tooltips for an image map. However when the hover happens, the tooltips appear below the entire image. I would like the tooltip to appear next to the area element. How would I accomplish this? Thanks.

jQuery:

```
$("#trigger1").tooltip({ 
    items: "area",
    content: "<div class='tooltipContent'><h3>1896</h3><p>Bemidji became a town</p></div>"
});
```

html (sample):

```
    <div ice:editable="*" class="top_banner" id="top_banner" style="position: relative;">
        <img alt="" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" usemap="#Map2" src="_images/timeline2.jpg" />
        <map id="Map2" name="Map2">
        <area id="trigger1" href="#" coords="21,99,12" shape="circle" />
        </map>
    </div>
```

live page: http://www.securitybankusa.com/about-test.htm

Comment: tooltip() has a position option that can be set, you'd have to use that with the position of the area.

Comment: @adeneo That is useful, but it still bases it off of the image instead of the area shape.

Comment: With position you can specify an 'of' attribute, which is an ID to base the positioning on, and also use 'using:function(position,feedback){$(this.css(position);} to give it the correct position

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your tooltip to be positioned whichever way you want.

Documentation on position option: 
http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position